# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance"? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, instance, selector

I've read several other forums on this issue but none of the solutions have worked for me, where am I going wrong? The error is on the button: "[Project.SignUpViewController signUpButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance XXX".

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var credField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func toSignUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credField.text!, password: passField.text!, completion: { (authResult, error) in
        //
        })
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(usernameField.text!).setData([
        "basics": ["name": nameField.text!, "username": usernameField.text!, "email": credField.text!]
        ])

    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is DetailViewController
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
        vc?.username = usernameField.text!
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
}
```

Comment: I guess you named the method first `@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton)` but decided to rename it afterwards `@IBAction func toSignUp(_ sender: UIButton)`. You need to go on the Storyboard, remove the previous link that linked the Tap of the button to the previously named method and redo it to the current method.

Comment: @Larme Ohh thank you so much!